# How to manage users on backend when using Auth0 Lock?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, auth0

I am creating a frontend with React and a backend with Node. I would like to manage user information using [Auth0 Lock](https://auth0.com/lock) - sending a JWT with each request to the API.

What if I need to do one of the following things?

- Store a blog post with an author ID

The Auth0 unique identifier is `user_id`, which is not an integer and therefore cannot be used as an ID/key. How would I handle this on a server-side user store?

- Have a users table to store a "profile about" or other similar information

Do I read the JWT on each API request, determine if that user exists, and then create a new user if it doesn't, or relate it to a pre-existing user if it does. Is it performant to check the user database on every single API request?

I am unsure how to handle general flow with JWT-based API and Auth0.

Edit:

My thoughts after some research and reflection: Auth0's unique user identifier is provided by them as `user_id`. The problem here is that it is not an integer. Therefore it should not be used as the key for the `users` table in a database.

It seems as if you shouldn't check the user database on each request, but this may be incorrect. One idea would be to callback to the backend on initial login, if the account doesn't exist, create it, if the account does exist, move on. Then just trust the Auth0 JWT (if it verifies on the backend) on each following request after the user has logged in on the frontend.

From the very few descriptions of this process I have seen online, it seems like the way I described was the normal way. But there are some situations where it doesn't make sense. What if a user was to be banned? They could still access the server functionality with their active JWT until it expires due to time.

So, if it is normal/performant to check the user store on each API request, how do I relate Auth0's string id, `user_id`, to an integer ID in the datastore to do queries? I am using a SQL variant.

Comment: The way to solve your issue about banned users is to use a cache. On first call, your app checked the cache, if they don't exist, the cache will try to get them from the database, then return that user info. When the user is banned, the ban code must also clear the user from the cache, so that next time the new data is pulled, it gets the banned flag too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### How to identify users

You're not explicit about which database technology you use, but in general you should be able to use regular strings as identifiers/keys. You do mention that you're using SQL variant so that may be the source of the issue; you should probably use a more specific text-based data type with a fixed length enough.

The `user_id` is the result of concatenating the Auth0 identity provider identifier with the user identifier within that provider so we could argue that reaching a definitive max length is a little trickier. However, you can decide on arbitrary value, for example, something like 640 character ought to be enough for anyone.

You can also identify your users by email; this works if every authentication provider being used by your application requires users to provide their email and you also don't intend to support different accounts with the same email address.

A final alternative is for you to assign each user your own unique identifier that is better suited for how you intend to use it. You can achieve this by having an [Auth0 rule update your user metadata](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/metadata-in-rules#updating-metadata) with this new attribute and then request this attribute to be [included in the generated token upon user authentication by the means of scopes](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes#requesting-specific-claims).

Depending on the approach you would neither need a simple lookup table mapping one form of identifier to your internal one or in the case you update the user metadata with your internal identifier you could skip that lookup table entirely and just the value coming from the JWT.

#### How to handle first-time users

Like you mentioned, you could at each API request make sure that if this is the first request issued by a new user then you create your notion of application profile before processing the request.

The alternative to this would be triggering this application profile creation from within Auth0 when you detect that the user signup for the first time and then on the API always assume the profile exists.

Both approaches are valid; I would go with the one that would leave you with a simpler implementation and still meets your requirements.

#### How to handle users being banned

If you do need to support the ability to immediately ban a user and don't allow any other request to the API then you'll always have to have some kind of query at each API request to see if the user was banned or not. This increases the complexity significantly so do consider that you can tolerate a solution where the lifetime of a token is shorter and banned users may still call your API within that short time frame.

Comment: So I feel like this may be the best option: Add a Auth0 rule to give each user's JWT a unique integer ID (Still figuring out how to do this). Then, on every login (from Auth0 Lock on the frontend), callback to the Node backend and create/update a user in the MySQL user table using the information from the JWT. The unique integer ID created from the Auth0 rule will be used as the primary key.

Will this work? Any changes or suggestions you have?

Comment: Yes, that will work; just two minor notes, on the rules your work and update the user profile not the JWT directly, but it has the same end result. Additionally, you don't need to make a call to the backend on every login, you can do it on the first login and on subsequent logins just skip that step. Check [this sample rule](https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/rules/signup.md) for something similar.

Comment: But if I wanted the user record to update, say, if they changed the email or name of the Facebook account they use to log in, then I would need to call on each login? Also, is there a sample rule of adding a unique ID? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In that case, you're correct, you would update at each login to maintain the data synchronized. I'm not aware of any existing sample rule that adds unique identifiers.

Comment: After some research, it seems like it would be impossible to add sequential unique identifiers to the user using rules, because rules seemingly have no notion of the previous users. I am having trouble thinking of a solution for this. How is this (storing auth0 users on local server data store) handled in past applications? This has to have been done before lol, I just can't find it.

Comment: This is one of the only examples I can find of someone with a backend example where they are looking up users. They are querying the database on `user.sub`. Is this recommended or performant? Would looking up on a String be slow on a MySQL database, or is this okay? http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/setup-nodejs-api-server-powered-by-passport-auth0-strategy/

Comment: In order to use a sequential identifier from a rule you could call an external service. In relation to the example, `user.sub` should be the `user_id` information provided by Auth0 and I'm no DB expert, but it should be more than feasible and performant to have a query on a fixed-length char column.

Comment: @Connorelsea how did you end up solving this? I am on the same boat, and I am surprised there's no samples or documentation around maintaining user profiles in the application's backend. My current thinking is that my callback endpoint would issue a call to the backend so that the backend knows that a user signed in, but not sure if this is the right way to go. It seems like it could go wrong, and my app would end up in a bad state if the user doesn't get created in the backend.